# TCG design specification of TPM and nonce creation

Tags: terminology, trusted-platform-module

I am reading [TPM Main Part 1 Design Principles](https://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/files/resource_files/646BE624-1D09-3519-ADDA61BE37A21A74/mainP1DPrev103.pdf) (PDF) which states:

> The creation of all nonce values MUST use the next $n$ bits from the TPM RNG.

I do not know what this means, or how to find out what it means. What is “the next $n$ bits”?  There is no other comment or hint on this section which might explain $n$
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cryptography, $n$ is frequently used to point to some specific number.

The statement

> The creation of all nonce values MUST use the next $n$ bits from the TPM RNG.

simply clarifies that all nonce values have to be generated using the TPM RNG, by using/extracting the next $n$ number of bits from that RNG. Maybe it helps to think of “$n$ bits” as “x number of bits”, where “x” is the amount specified in the paper.

So, if a paper explains that (for example) a *“nonce size is 64 bits”* and later states you have to extract the next $n$ bits from some function or RNG to initialize that nonce, $n$ would be 64. Taking this example, the line you’ve stumbled upon would mean: “The creation of all nonce values MUST use the next ***64*** bits from the TPM RNG.”

But please note that that‘s merely an example. If a paper would point to 32 bits, or 128 bits, or whatever other number of bits, $n$ would have to be interpreted as another number/count/amount accordingly. Also note that we are talking about bits in this specific case and paper. Other papers might as well use $n$ to mention “$n$ bytes” or other units (eg: “$n$ rounds of encryption”).

Comment: There's a consequence to that requirement: the number of bits drawn from TPM RNG is fully specified; and if the TPM RNG output is known, and all its uses similarly specified, what's produced is known (except for bit order). An implementor can not e.g. get $64\lceil n/64\rceil$ bits of the TPM RNG; or/and massage the bits from the TPM RNG. Such specification makes software modules independently testable as black boxes (by replacing TRNG with PRNG or fixed balues). It also makes rigging the TPM RNG a surer way to get the thing pwned, which depending on position is a goal, or not.